# Turning off default video output with xrandr when external monitor is connected

Tags: bash, video, bash-script, xrandr

I'm new to bash scripting, and I'm trying to configure my video outputs so that my laptop display gets turned off when I connect an external monitor via VGA.

That's the script I came up with, pretty straightforward:

```
#!/bin/bash
myvar="$(xrandr -q)"
if [[ $myvar == *"VGA connected"* ]]
    then
        xrandr --output VGA --auto;
        xrandr --output LVDS --off;
    else
        xrandr --output LVDS --auto;
fi
```

All is working as it should except for the `xrandr --output LVDS --off` bit, as my laptop display simply adjusts its resolution to match the external monitor's one and stays on.

Can't figure out the bug on this one. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Does `--output LVDS --off` work correctly when run directly from the shell?

Can you swap the lines in the `then`-part? Maybe there are some timing issues?

Comment: Yes, the command works properly when given from shell. I should have mentioned that. Also, swapping the lines has no effect whatsoever. So, no timing issues here.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `xset` command (https://linux.die.net/man/1/xset ).

Instead of:

```
xrandr --output LVDS --off
```

use something like:

```
xset -display :0 dpms force off
```

I'm assuming that `:0` is your laptop display.